# How can i add a css rule for this code?

Tags: html, css

The problem is i don't know how to apply a css rule for 'Search example.com' text, more accurately i don't know what to do because the text is not closed between tags.

This code is generated by javascript ([support.google.com](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136085))

This is the code:

```
<div id="goog-wm">
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="other-things"><b>Other things to try:</b></h3>
    <ul>
      <li class="search-goog"><script type="text/javascript"> a code here... </script> Search <b>example.com</b>:
        <form method="get" onsubmit="return ss(this)">
          <input type="text" value="blablabla" id="goog-wm-qt" name="q" size="40">
          <input type="submit" id="goog-wm-sb" value="Google Search">
        </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: this how it looks]

What i want to do is to apply a 20px margin between the search box and the text...

How can i do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you alter the HTML at all?

Comment: the code is generated by the google javascript from the link and i can not do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you apply a `20px` top margin to the form?

```
.search-goog form { margin-top: 20px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the *20px margin* rule on the very next form of the `li.search-goog` element(s) :

```
.search-goog > form {
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
li.search-goog form { 
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#goog-wm .content ul li.search-goog {
 /* css here */
}
```

That should allow you to style the text. You can then start removing declarations from left to right until it stops working.... You may only need....

```
li.search-goog {
/* css here */
}
```